# How to use Mac Developer Certificate with codesign tool to sign Java application?

Tags: java, macos, signing

I am using [Oracle App Bundler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) to sign my Java application for OSX. I use this following commands to sign my application:

```
codesign -f -s "MyName" dist/MyCool.app
codesign -vv dist/MyCool.app
```

"MyName" is a self-signed certificate common name that I created with Key Chain Access. It went well, although OSX gives warning that it come from untrusted developer. Now that I have create a Mac Developer certificate from our Apple Developer subscription, how do I use it? I have already imported the downloaded `mac_development.cer` into Key Chain Access, but using its common name, `codesign` still complain `no identity found`.

How do I properly import it into my development environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The codesign command should be:

```
codesign -s "Developer ID Application: Certificate Common Name" dist/MyCool.app
```

You also need to add the intermediate certificates from Apple (in case you haven't added those to your keychain).

- Developer ID Certification Authority
- Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority (WWDR)

  1. http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/
  2. Download the Intermediate Certificates listed.
  3. Add them to your keychain

Also, take a look at the [Apple Developer Codesigning Workflow Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH12-SW2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll have a test on it on my system. But, yet I haven't add any intermediate certificate. Is it necessary? I am not planning to ship my app to Apple Store. Just would like to have users seeing that the application is signed from a trusted developer

Comment: Great. Thanks to pointed me to the that CA link. Actually, after my account was setup as Admin in my team, I am finally able to create my own certificate. Previously XCode complained that My certificate missing its private key. I think I ought to told you about it. That's the real problem. And about that common name, I simply use the full common name from my certificate : `3rd Party Mac Developer Application: ***`. I am also able to use the Mac Development certificate earlier. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I confirm that this solution works! Now I am using "Developer ID Application: xxx" common name